# Linq to XML: All descendants with a specific name

Tags: xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have the following XML:

```
<Document>
   <CustomerCopy>
      <PrintDestination>PDF</PrintDestination>
      <NumberOfCopies>1</NumberOfCopies>
   </CustomerCopy>
   <CLientCopy>
      <PrintDestination>PDF</PrintDestination>
      <NumberOfCopies>1</NumberOfCopies>
   </ClientCopy>
   <GovernmentCopy>
      <PrintDestination>PDF</PrintDestination>
      <NumberOfCopies>1</NumberOfCopies>
   </GovernmentCopy>
</Document>
```

How do I get a collection of all the PrintDestination? Is there a way to do that without listing each distinct parent? I don't need the parent, just the PrintDestination elements. I just want to see if they are all PDF.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well, there is a `Descendants("PrintDestination")` method you can call.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is...

```
PrintSettingsXml.Descendants("PrintDestination");
```

I just didn't look hard enough.